# How do I get all the instance variables of an object without using its getter methods?

Tags: java, reflection, instance-variables

I have POJO class

```
Class Book {
private String id;
private String title;

Public Book() {
}

//implement setter and getter
..............

}

main() {
Book book = new Book();
book.setId(1);
book.setTitle("new moon");

}
```

How to get all instance variable of book object
I want the result become -> 1, "new moon" 
without using the getter method, so I can convert the other POJO object.

---

Clarification:

I have 2 classes

```
Book {
String id;
String title;

//constructor

//setter
}

Student {
    String id;
    String name;

    //cuonstructor

    //setter
}

main() {
Book book = new Book();
book.setId(1);
book.setTitle("new moon");

Student student = new Student();
student.setId(1);
student.setName("andrew");

//suppose i have BeanUtil object to get all instance varable value and class meta data
BeanUtil.getMetadata(book, Book.class);
//output is
//id, title

//suppose i have BeanUtil object to get all instance varable value and class meta data
BeanUtil.getMetadata(student, Students.class);
//output is
//id, name

BeanUtil.getInstanceVariableValue(student, Student.class);
//output
//1, andrew

BeanUtil.getInstanceVariableValue(book, Book.class);
//output
//1, new moon
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I want to get all value of the object instance without using book.getId() , book.getTitle()

Answer (score 3):

I generally use [PropertyUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html) which is part of [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/).

```
//get all of the properties for a POJO
descriptors = PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(book);
//go through all values
Object value = null;
for ( int i = 0; i < descriptors.length; i++ ) {
     value = PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty(bean, descriptors[i].getName())
 }         
//copy properties from POJO to POJO
PropertyUtils.copyProperties(fromBook, toBook);
```

Comment: Thanks Matt ..

But it just get all properties of the object.

how abut getting all instance variable value ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the values of all attributes of a Book instance, you could do this using reflection.  However, that would require a lot of code, and would be expensive.  A better approach is (IMO) to simply implement a `getAllValues()` method:

```
public Object[] getAllValues() {
    return new Object[]{this.id, this.title};
}
```

or better still, have it populate and return a Map or a Properties object.  I guess it depends on your use-cases which is better.  (Though I'm having difficulty comprehending why you would want the values of all attributes in an array / list ...)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public static String getMetadata(Class input) {
  StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
  // this will get all fields declared by the input class
  Field[] fields = input.getDeclaredFields();
  for (int i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      result.append(", ");
    }
    field[i].setAccessible(true);
    result.append(field[i].getName());
  }
}

public static String getInstanceVariableValue(Object input) {
  StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
  // this will get all fields declared by the input object
  Field[] fields = input.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
  for (int i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      result.append(", ");
    }
    fields[i].setAccessible(true);
    result.append(fields[i].get(input));
  }
    return result;
}
```

I've not tried to compile or run this so let me know how it goes

Comment: Your code will be conflicted if the access modifier of instance variable set to private

can you give me another suggestion ?

Comment: @martinatime. Just a suggestion, if you want to access `private` attributes also, do `field.setAccessible(true)` before using the `field`. If you don't want the access to `private` attributes, use `getClass().getFields()`, instead of `getClass().getDeclaredFields()`.

Comment: but *remember* that `getFields()` also returns all public fields from the superclasses!

Comment: I was basically taking the link that I included in my other answer and wrote up some quick code snippets as examples. I didn't try to compile or run them as I leave that as an exercise for @adisembiring. 

@Vinegar thanks for hints. I'll update my snippets

Comment: Can you just override toString on your object and have it return a string with all the fields you care about? You can auto generate this with intelliJ

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the point of your project (I assume a homework project?) is to learn [Reflections](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/).

- [Fields](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields())
- [Methods](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods())

Answer (score 0):

Like Michael, I'm not sure I understand your question fully.  It sounds like you want to be able to get a Book object given a String containing its title.  Assuming you've declared your Book class as above, try this:

```
public class Book {
    private String id;
    private String title;

    public Book(String id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    // Setters and getters...

}

public class Library {
    private Map<String, Book> booksByTitle = new HashMap<String, Book>();

    public Library() {
    }

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        this.booksByTitle.put(book.getTitle(), book);
    }

    public Book getBookByTitle(String title) {
        // Returns null if no matching entry is found in the map.
        return this.booksByTitle.get(title);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Library myLibrary = new Library();

        myLibrary.addBook(new Book("1", "new moon"));
        myLibrary.addBook(new Book("2", "fight club"));

        Book book = myLibrary.getBookByTitle("new moon");

        if (book == null) {
            // A book by that title is not in the library
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what adisembiring is asking is how to get the values in his POJO without calling the individual getters for each instance variable. There is a way to do this using reflection. [Here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55) is an article on how to create toString() methods and starting with Example #2 it uses the Reflection API to dynamically determine what to output.